# How to serialize custom user model in DRF

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have made a custom user model,by referring the [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) , this is how I serialize the new user model:

**Serializers.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Listing.objects.all())
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','post')
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

But when I tried to use this serializer,I get

> 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

use

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Remember that `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is just a `string` that indicates which user model you will use not the model itself. If you want to get the model, use `get_user_model`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But for django 1.8 it should be `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`

Comment: @levi Thanks for the answer, just a small correction is needed. You have written "from from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model"
Please update it to single from.